# ImportError: cannot import name ResponseError

Tags: apache, mod-python, urllib3

I am trying to use mod_python.
however when i try to access my page I get following error.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/mod_python/importer.py", line 1540, in HandlerDispatch
    default=default_handler, arg=req, silent=hlist.silent)

  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/mod_python/importer.py", line 1205, in _process_target
    module = import_module(module_name, path=path)

  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/mod_python/importer.py", line 299, in import_module
    log, import_path)

  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/mod_python/importer.py", line 683, in import_module
    execfile(file, module.__dict__)

  File "/var/www/pylons-data/prod/reports/scripts/access_reports.py", line 2, in <module>
    import requests

  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/requests/__init__.py", line 60, in <module>
    from .api import request, get, head, post, patch, put, delete, options

  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 14, in <module>
    from . import sessions

  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 27, in <module>
    from .adapters import HTTPAdapter

  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 29, in <module>
    from .packages.urllib3.exceptions import ResponseError

ImportError: cannot import name ResponseError
```

Any help is appreciated. not sure how i can fix

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Make sure that yours module is in sys.path list

Comment: funny thing is we have 3 servers almost identical and the mod_python code works in 2 servers except this one. I am not able to figure out what is different here. Also all the changes are via ansible so they have to be identical on all severs